# No text printed when using response.xpath() or response.css in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to extract the text from a website using scrapy, when I use

```
        print("hello")
        data = response.xpath('//div[@class="content-blog"]/text()').get()
        print(data)
```

The output is

```
hello
```

Removing the `/text()` gives the entire HTML content as the output.

```
<div class="content-blog">
                                                       <p><strong><i>Title</i></strong><br>
Text paragraph1</p>
<p>Text paragraph2</p>
<p>Text paragraph3<br>
Text paragraph4</p>
<style id="bwg-style-0">    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 {      width: 1004px;      justify-content: center;              margin-left: auto;        margin-right: aut
o;              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);            padding-left: 4px;      padding-top: 4px;      max-width: 100%;            }        #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2
_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item {      justify-content: flex-start;      max-width: 200px;          }    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item > a {       margin-righ
t: 4px;       margin-bottom: 4px;    }    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item0 {      padding: 0px;      background-color: #FFFFFF;      border: 0px none #CCCCCC;
      opacity: 1.00;      filter: Alpha(opacity=100);      border-radius: 0;      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;    }    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item1 im
g {      max-height: none;      max-width: none;      padding: 0 !important;    }        @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {      #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-
0 .bwg-item0 {        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;      }      #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item0:hover {        -ms-trans
form: scale(1.1);        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);        transform: scale(1.1);      }    }          #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-item1 {      padding-top
: 90%;    }        #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-title2,    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-ecommerce2 {      color: #CCCCCC;      font
-family: segoe ui;      font-size: 16px;      font-weight: bold;      padding: 2px;      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;      max-height: 100%;    }    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0
 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-play-icon2 {      font-size: 32px;    }    #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg-container-0 .bwg-ecommerce2 {      font-size: 19.2px;      color: #CCCCCC;    }
 </style>    <div id="bwg_container1_0" class="bwg_container bwg_thumbnail bwg_thumbnails" data-right-click-protection="0" data-bwg="0" data-lightbox-url=.... </div>
```

The same thing happens when I use response.css().

The text I'm looking to extract is in multiple `<p>` tags which come under the `<div class="content-blog">` tag.

How do I get only the text from the website without the rest of the HTML ?
I'm using scrapy version - 2.2.0 and Python version - 3.7

Comment: Could you provide us with an URL and the exact data you require ? The xpath selector you've chosen will only get the text within the div tag element itself, not the child tags like <p>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As not much information has been given to get the paragraph text

```
data = response.xpath('//div[@class="content-blog"]/p/text()').getall()
```

This will get all p tags that are children from the div tag. Note the variable data will be a list. The getall() method grabs all tags specified in the XPATH selector.

Comment: This is gives me the required text. I think I will be able to handle the data from the list. Thank you.

Comment: Could you tick the answer as the accept one ? The tick at the left hand side of my answer. Thanks. Glad I could help!

Comment: I tried this solution for a few of the websites I'm trying to scrape, so far it works fine when  the HTML is structured like `<div class = "content-blog"> <p> </p></div>` but I also have a few websites which are structured like `<div class = 'content-blog'><div class = "col-sm-6"><p></p></div></div>` and this didn't work for these websites. Is there a solution that is general for both these situations ?

Comment: I think it's worth trying to learn abit about XPATH selectors as this will give you more flexibility in answering these types of questions yourself. We should be looking at the tag element where the text is contained. If there's a class attribute you can specify that directly with XPATH. so in this case '//div[@class="col-sm-6"]/p/text()' is the XPATH selector. You can select any tag and use '/' to keep going down the chain if necessary, but if the tag has a class attribute that is more specific and the XPATH selector text is shorter which is always more readable in code.

Comment: I will certainly read about XPATH selectors. I did not understand what you meant by the last sentence, can explain it please ?

Comment: You can chain down the HTML tree. That is if you have a div > p > you could do xpath '//div/p ' ... etc. But it's much better if those div's or p's have a class element or id element. The order of div > p in a website may change, but the class attribute/id attribute is less likely to change, we depend on HTML not changing to get the data we want. Therefore targeting tags with class attributes and using that in your XPATH selector. so '/p[@class="attribute"]/text()' is better than 'div/p/text(). means you're more likely to get the data you want and to continue to do so if you scrape it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS as well. As, CSS is easy to write and CSS is also converted to XPATH underhood.

```
data = response.css('.content-blog ::text').getall()
```